# Should I run a linear or binomial regression based on my data distribution?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, logistic-regression

In the attached image, the x-axis is the proportion of children at a school who passed at least 5 GCSE exams that year, and the y-axis is a count of the schools. The different colours are whether the school is in a rural or urban area.

I want to do a regression to see how the school being in a rural vs. urban area affects this measure of attainment:
`5_GCSEs ~ rural`.

I've read that if your dependent variable is a proportion (as mine is), it can be advisable to convert this into a count of successes out of the total number of trials (i.e. # pupils obtaining 5 GCSEs / # pupils sitting GCSEs) for each school and run a binomial logistic regression. However, you need to look at the data distribution first to determine if this is necessary.

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2HQH.png)

This looks quite normally distributed other than the second small peak around 1. Does this mean I can just use a linear regression?

I've also attached the residual plots and QQ plots. However, as the only independent variable is a binary variable, I'm not sure how to interpret these.

[residual plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxXb5.png)
[QQ plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzxOO.png)

Grateful for any suggestions about what the distribution of my data suggests about the type of regression analysis I should do.

Comment: Since this is more of a stats question consider using https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead. This site is still part of the StackOverflow family.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link - I've moved the question to there :)